# iPhone #import ApplicationServices?

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I'm trying to use `CGBitmapContextCreate`. According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate) the ApplicationServices framework is required. When I went to add it, it wasn't in the list available (the latest version of Xcode changes things a bit), but I managed to find it manually in the Frameworks folder. However, I'm still getting "framework not found" bugs and a full blown error if I `#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>`

Forgive my noobness. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the documentation is Mac specific, and hasn't been fixed for the iPhone. The CoreGraphics framework (on both Mac and iPhone) will work.